# How to do genders in mongoid and simpleform?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, simple-form

I have the following models:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_one :gender

class Gender
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

Gender table is seeded with genders.

My simpleform for user edit is as follows:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :gender, :collection => Gender.all, :prompt => "Choose a gender" %>
  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

However when I save this, a `user.gender` doesn't do anything.

Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see your logic is like this -

-one user has one gender

-one gender has many users

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :gender

class Gender
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :users
```

To get user's gender

```
user.gender
```

To users who has the same gender

```
gender.users
```

Comment: this is correct. my relationship is actually wrong... your relationship makes more sense.

i also had to add a gender_id, to my attr_accessor for it to save.

Answer (score 0):

Change your model as

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_one :gender

class Gender
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :user
```

And change your form field as:

```
<%= f.input :gender_id, :collection => Gender.all, :prompt => "Choose a gender" %>
```